# Use Report Builder to connect to SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am working on my senior project in college and we as a team are creating a web tracking application, and right now we at the point where we need find out how to create reports based on our DB.

We are using MS SQL server Express 2008, so here is my question: I know MS has Report Builder but I am wondering if you know if this builder will works with SQL server express 2008?

May be you can share some of the links how to use this product. I was searching but so far cannot find anything which can help me. Also does it allow me to run my own queries and connect this software to my db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad hoc report builder [doesn't work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365173.aspx) with SQL Server Express. Also you are not able to get the data from external databases. You may use the data from current instance of SQL Express only.

However you can consider some third party reporting tools. I'd advice our [SharpShooter Reports](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Report-Sharp-Shooter.aspx)). Please contact sales dept and let them know that you work on a college project. The tool is free for non-commercial college development (may be they will ask you to write a review).

Comment: this project is senior project for my program but also it is client tracking system for non-profit organisation, i think it can count as commercial development or it is still non-commercial college development?

Comment: Andrey, please contact sales@perpetuumsoft.com I suppose they will be glad to discuss the opportunities.